Using a local dev server for developing an Apollo GraphQL server V4 w/ AWS Lambda (Serverless)
I am trying to deploy a simple Apollo GraphQL V4 server with AWS Lambda. I have a very simple database (using Firebase Realtime data) that I want to get data from.
I was following this guide to deploying the server. I was originally trying to get serverless invoke local -f graphql -p query.json command to work, which itself was causing the below error:
✖ Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'

I realized using a dev server instead of serverless invoke local commands may be better.
How can I implement a local dev server? Do you have any suggestions?
The repo can be found here.
I have tried using v16, v18, v20, express, apollo-lambda-express, serverless, serverless-offline to set up a local dev server, but have not been able to.

You already have serverless-offline in your serverless.yml, so npx sls offline start should fire up the local API and you can send requests to it.
